# filter a rendered grid result from selectbox value in jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

UPDATE: my question became lot simpler I think. how can I do to tell:

```
 var query = $(":input[name=filter]").val(),
```

To take `$("select[name=PR_Type]").val(),` as parameter? 
I tried something like this:

```
var query = $(":input[name=filter]").val() || $("select[name=PR_Type]").val(),
```

but this take only $("select[name=PR_Type]").val(),as filter result...

---

Im trying to filter a result based on a value selected from a selectbox. The `renderResult()` function renders a grid that has some labels and the rendered data and it looks something like this:

```
renderResult: function () {
 var query = $(":input[name=filter]").val(),
 querySelect = $("select[name=PR_Type]").val(),
 queryRegexp = query === "" ? undefined : new RegExp(query, "i"), 
 console.time("productos.renderResult()");
     $("#result").html("");
         productos.sort();
     $.each(productos.models, function (i, row) {
     if (!row.transformed) {...
```

So I came up with something like this:

```
$('[name=PR_Type]').on('change', function (event) {

        var selection = $(this).val(), //Changed here and now I get the value

        products.renderResult(selection);
    });
```

and a selectbox like this:

```
<select name="PR_Type"></select>
```

This selectbox get its values from a json file that connects to the servlet. and this is how I set the options to the selectbox:

```
 var types = [];
    for (var type in productos.productosTypes) types.push(productos.productosTypes[type] + "|" + type);
    $("[name=PR_Type]").setOptions(types);
```

I also created a function to get the values to do something like this:

```
this.getValue("PR_Type"),
```

but Im not sure how to implement this anymore

```
getValue: function (name) {
        var $elemSelect = $("select[name=" + name + "]");
        return $elemSelect.val() ? escape($elemSelect.val()) : "";
    },
```

I know Im missing something on the $('[name=PR_Type]').on('change', function (event) { but im not sure what it is. Thanks everyone in advance for any advise!

Comment: UPDATE: I changed ....on('change', function (event) {
        var selection = $('select[name=PR_Type]').val(); ..... to  var selection = $(this).val(); and now I get the value of the select but still cant display only the results with that value 

    });

Comment: NEW UPDATE: now I see that where I should chenge is in renderResult() but my question is now a lot simpler I think... How do I say that  var query = $(":input[name=filter]").val(),
can as well take $("select[name=PR_Type]").val(), as parameter?

Comment: Would you mind creating a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net) that produces the same result? With a fiddle, others can see your code and edit the fiddle to give you an answer with a working example.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ferdinand1985/0wasfy24/    I created a jsfiddle with my renderResult() function, I found where the problem is, but I dont know how to fix it. In the renderResult() function (row 25 on the jsfiddle) has a RegExp to display de filtered results... well, that is creating my headache... Well now is the filtering "working" but it doesnt load the grid if I dont specifie the PR_Type. why is that happening??

Comment: and I think the problem lays on row 58 in the jsfiddle @DonShrout :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! All the poroblem lays in renderResult() there I tried to look if the selectbox value was empty or null, which it was wrong. I should look if it was null ori undefined, then I had to change a litle bit the regExp if scentence. So at the end I changed this:

```
querySelect = $("select[name=PR_Type]").val(),
queryRegexp = query === "" ? undefined : new RegExp(query, "i"),
```

and added this:

```
querySelectRegexp = querySelect === null ? undefined : new RegExp(querySelect, "i"),
```

so now it looks like this:

```
renderResult: function () {
        var query = $(":input[name=filter]").val(),
            querySelect = $("select[name=PR_Type]").val(),
            queryRegexp = query === "" ? undefined : new RegExp(query, "i"), 
            querySelectRegexp = querySelect === null ? undefined : new RegExp(querySelect, "i"),
```

And the regExp if scentence was like this:

```
  if (querySelectRegexp !== undefined) {

                    if (queryRegexp !== undefined) {
                        if (row.name.match(queryRegexp)) {
                            row.classes = row.classes.replace(/hide/g, "");
                        } else {
                            if (row.classes.indexOf("hide") === -1) {
                                row.classes += " hide";
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (querySelectRegexp !== undefined) { (row.type.match(querySelectRegexp)) {
                            row.classes = row.classes.replace(/hide/g, "");
                        } else {
                            if (row.classes.indexOf("hide") === -1) {
                                row.classes += " hide";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        row.classes = row.classes.replace(/hide/g, "");
                    }
```

and now it looks like this:

```
  if (querySelectRegexp !== undefined) {
                        if (row.type.match(querySelectRegexp)) {
                            row.classes = row.classes.replace(/hide/g, "");
                        } else {
                            if (row.classes.indexOf("hide") === -1) {
                                row.classes += " hide";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (queryRegexp !== undefined) {
                        if (row.name.match(queryRegexp)) {
                            row.classes = row.classes.replace(/hide/g, "");
                        } else {
                            if (row.classes.indexOf("hide") === -1) {
                                row.classes += " hide";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        row.classes = row.classes.replace(/hide/g, "");
                    }
```

Comment: Excellent! Good job!